# How to delete a Telegram user id when user delete the chat of the bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I'm building a telegram bot using pyTelegramBotAPI libraries, I wanted to know if there is a way to know when a user deletes a chat with my bot, so the bot will not send more messages towards that specific id.
reading the telegram API I found nothing, can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Bot API 5.1 introduces a new update type represented by [ChatMemberUpdated](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberupdated) class.

When a user blocks your bot you will now receive an update looking like this:

```
{
   "update_id":111627970,
   "my_chat_member":{
      "chat":{...},
      "from":{...},
      "date":1116140500,
      "old_chat_member":{...},
      "new_chat_member":{
         "user":{...},
         "status":"kicked",
         "until_date":0
      }
   }
}
```

Handle this update accordingly. It has all relevant information to let you exclude a user, who has blocked your bot.

**Old answer:**

Sadly you can't know when a user has deleted a chat with your bot.

You can keep sending messages though. Eventually the user will block your bot.

Trying to send a message to a user who has blocked your bot will give you HTTP status code error 403.

> 403: Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user

Only then you can safely delete a user's chat_id from your list.

Answer (score 1):

> As I know, there is no way. When you chat with a friend, is there any way to know that he/she has deleted the chat page of you? NO.
>
> Telegram bot is completely similar to simple chat in this case up to
>   this date. It doesn't have considered in Telegram Bot API up to this
>   date.